# Grails / Groovy Attribute value quote wasn't closed : Google Visualization API - data from Domain Class

Tags: grails, google-maps-api-3, gsp

I am using GGTS: 3.6.4, 
Grails: 2.4.4
jdk 1.7.51
google-visualization:1.0

I am trying to pass data from a domain class to my view to display a map using the Google Visualization plug-in. I believe I am passing this data to my GSP incorrectly. I can make the data render on screen, in text, in the acceptable format, please see my GSP for ***def mapData***.

When I use

```
def mapData =[<g:each in="${places}" var="place" status="i">[${place.lat}, ${place.lon}, "${place.name }"],</g:each>]
```

I get this error:
     Message:Attribute value quote wasn't closed (elementId="map" columns= "${mapColumns}" data= "[

Any tips on how I can change my GSP to get the data from my domain class?

**Domain Class:**

```
package zmapapp

class ThingLoc {
String name
Float lat
Float lon

static constraints = {

    lat()
    lon()
    name()
  }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
  package zmapapp


class ThingLocController {

def scaffold = true


def map (){
    def places = ThingLoc.list()
    [places: places]
}
}
```

**GSP:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Google Visualization API plugin</title>
    <meta name="layout" content="main" />
    <gvisualization:apiImport/>
</head>
   <body>
   <%

      def mapColumns = [['number', 'Lat'], ['number', 'Lon'], ['string', 'Name']]
      def mapData = [[37.4232, -122.0853, 'Work'], [37.4289, -122.1697, 'University'], [37.6153, -122.3900, 'Airport'], [37.4422, -122.1731, 'Shopping']]


   %>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function selectHandler(e) {
          alert('A table row was selected');
      }

      function readyHandler(e) {
          console.log('Table is ready');
      }
   </script>

   <h2>See Map Below   </h2>

   <gvisualization:map elementId="map" 

   columns= "${mapColumns}" 
   data= "${mapData}"     />



   <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">

         <td>
            <a href="http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/map">Map</a>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 300px"></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>


           [<g:each in="${places}" var="place" status="i">[${place.lat}, ${place.lon}, "${place.name }"],</g:each>]


</body>
```

Comment: as it sits the GSP is working but the mapData is static, I have a <g:each tag down below that renders the domain class data in the format above.

Comment: added to original description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using the def mapColumns or mapData and instead used the google syntax found here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/map

**here's my update gsp:**

```
    <html>
 <head>
     <title>Dat Map tho</title>
<meta name="layout" content="main" />
<gvisualization:apiImport/>

 <script type="text/javascript">

google.load('visualization', '1', { 'packages': ['map'] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

 function drawMap() {
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['Lat', 'Long', 'Name'],

   <g:each in="${places}" var="place" status="i">[${place.lat}, ${place.lon}, "${place.name }"],</g:each> 

   ]);

var options = { showTip: true };

var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

map.draw(data, options);
 };
</script>

</head>
<body>

  <div id="chart_div"></div>
<br><br>

  <a   href="http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/map">Map Visualization Information</a>

  </body>
     </html>
```